# How to get the KeyVault name in the notebook from the keyvault link in Synapse?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-link

How to get the KeyVault name in the notebook from the keyvault link in Synapse?

I need the KeyVault name to pass to the TokenLibrary.

`TokenLibrary.getSecret(keyVaultName,"MyConnectionString", "AzureKeyVaultLink")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to get the secret without the key vault name. There is an API called

```
Token.getSecretWithLS("AzureKeyVaultLink", "MyConnectionString"));
```

which will get the secret from the KV.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to enable ***managed service identity*** and add ***keyvault*** secrets and also add ***linked service*** to azure synapse

Go Azure key Vault in my case **`keyvam`** is ***KeyVault*** name.

[image: Ref]

**Syntax:**

```
connection_string = TokenLibrary.getSecret("mykeyvault", "ConnectionString")
```

you can use linked service as shown in the below reference.

```
connection_string = TokenLibrary.getSecret("mykeyvault", "ConnectionString", "AzureKeyVaultLinkedServiceName")
```

**Sample example:**

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sc = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
token_library = sc._jvm.com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.TokenLibrary
connection_string = token_library.getSecret('keyvam','vamsi')
print(connection_string)
```

[image: Ref2]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/445496/access-secret-from-vault-using-synapse-pyspark-not.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/445496/access-secret-from-vault-using-synapse-pyspark-not.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-secure-credentials-with-tokenlibrary?pivots=programming-language-python&WT.mc_id=data-34417-abhishgu#getsecret

https://dzone.com/articles/securely-access-azure-sql-database-from-azure-syna

Comment: I don't have problem accessing the keyvault. I want to programmatically get the keyvault name so that I can pass it to getSecret.

Comment: hi @XavierJohn, there is no proper way to get the key vault name programmatically, if you are using Azure CLI you will get the key vault name but that's a different process. Following the above reference, you can pass it to getSecret.

Comment: The problem is the name of the key vault is different in each environment so I am currently passing it as a parameter to the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be used for getting keyvault url associated with the linked service.

```
import sys
my_linked_service_name = "LS_Keyvault"
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
token_library = spark_session._jvm.com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.TokenLibrary
keyvaultUrl = token_library.getFullConnectionStringAsMap(my_linked_service_name).get("url")
```